# My touchpad stops working when my computer's memory is full

Tags: touchpad

Sometimes my computer runs out of memory (or overwise bugs somehow for a few seconds), and after that touchpad stops reacting to anything. Is there any way to get it back to life without reloading?

Comment: I'm sure that it stops responding because the Xserver freeze, there isn't anything to fix here, but buy more memory or find the underlying cause to the memory leaks.

Comment: Can I restart it without reloading?

Comment: Yes. The CD, DVD or USB flash drive you installed from? Please go back to that, boot from it, and choose MEMTEST for an overnight memory test, so we may rule out a bad memory DIMM or a bad memory connection.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that this is because you do not have Swap enabled.

Swap space will allow your computer to continue functioning after you run out of memory.

See more at: [Ubuntu Swap Faq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq)

Comment: I think I have large enough swap. I'm not sure it's because of memory either. Sometimes my pc doesn't react for a few seconds, and if I use touchpad at this time, after it "unfreeses", touchpad doesn't react. It's like "How you moved your cursor so fast, I don't know what to do!".

Comment: Swap should be 1-2 X your RAM chip memory.